# Optimizing C code -> CodeChef solution time exceeded

Tags: c, performance, optimization, time-complexity

What are tips and tricks so that my code can be executed in the given time limit? Maybe some logical changes or anything.

When I submit my solution in CodeChef it shows time limit exceeded, but I think it is fast enough simple code. How could it be executed within the time limit, i.e. 3 seconds?

#### Code

```
long int iv, aia[1000][1000];
long int imax = 0;
long int score(int ia, int ib);

int main() {

    int ii, ij;
    long int iut, ivt, ie;

    memset(aia, 0, 1000000);

    scanf("%d %d", &iv, &ie);

    if((iv <= 1000) && (iv >= 2)) {

        if((ie >= (iv-1)) && (ie <= ( (iv*(iv-1)) / 2) )) {

            for(ii = 0; ii<ie; ii++) {

                scanf("%d%d", &iut, &ivt);

                if((iut >= 0) && (ivt <= (iv -1))) {

                    scanf("%d", &aia[iut][ivt]);

                    if(aia[iut][ivt] < 0) {

                        return 1;
                    }

                    aia[ivt][iut] = aia[iut][ivt];
                }
                else {

                    return 1;
                }
            }

            for(ii = 0; ii<iv; ii++) {

                for(ij = 0; ij<iv; ij++) {

                   printf("%d ", score(ii, ij));
                   imax = 0;
                }

                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


long int score(int ia, int ib) {

    int ii;
    int long imaxt = 0;

    if(ia == ib) {

        return 0;
    }

    if(aia[ia][ib] != 0) {

        imax = aia[ia][ib];
    }

    for(ii = 0; ii<iv; ii++) {

        if((ii != ib) && (ii != ia)) {

            if(aia[ia][ii] != 0) {

                if(aia[ii][ib] != 0) {

                    imaxt = (aia[ia][ii] < aia[ii][ib]) ? aia[ia][ii] : aia[ii][ib];

                    if(imaxt > imax) {

                        imax = imaxt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return imax;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice to you is to run your code through a profiler. I personally prefer [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Then when you find the bottleneck, you could have a go at it or post it here instead of the long listing.

Comment: Your point is very valid. But this should probably rather be a comment than an answer.

Comment: The OP asked for any help and suggestions, I didn't want to do his work for him, so I provided a push in the right direction.

Comment: there is no memory leak problem ...
I need suggestions so that I could optimize it to prevent the exceeded time.

Comment: profiling doesn't just detect memory leaks, it could show you where your code spends most time, so you can focus on optimizing the significant portions of the code, instead of wasting time.

Comment: thank you a lot.. I use windows 7 kindly tell me which profiler would best fit my needs